# XDocReport converting ODT to PDF with OSGI

Tags: java, osgi, itext, xdocreport, odftoolkit

To start to work with XDocReport I want to convert ODT to PDF.

All my application is OSGi. So I install the following bundles:

```
fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter-1.0.5.jar
fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core-1.0.5.jar
fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document-1.0.5.jar
fr.opensagres.xdocreport.itext.extension-1.0.5.jar
fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template-1.0.5.jar
```

Besides in class path I have `itext-4.2.1.jar` (it is not OSGi bundle) and I
export the following packages:

```
  <package name="com.lowagie.text"/>
  <package name="com.lowagie.text.factories"/>
  <package name="com.lowagie.text.pdf"/>
  <package name="com.lowagie.text.pdf.draw"/>
```

However, I don't get converter using the following code:

```
Options options = Options.getFrom(DocumentKind.ODT).to(ConverterTypeTo.PDF);
IConverter converter = ConverterRegistry.getRegistry().getConverter(options);
in = new FileInputStream(new File("/Temp/Test1.odt"));
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("/Temp/Test1.pdf"));
converter.convert(in, out, options); //HERE I GET NullPointerException - converter is null.
```

Trying to solve this problem I added the following bundles:

```
org.odftoolkit.odfdom.converter.core-1.0.5.jar
org.odftoolkit.odfdom.converter.pdf-1.0.5.jar
```

However, I get:

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle
>   org.odftoolkit.odfdom.converter.core [43]: Unable to resolve 43.0:
>   missing requirement [43.0] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (osgi.wiring.package=org.odftoolkit.odfdom.dom)

To solve problem with `org.odftoolkit.odfdom.dom` I added `odfdom-java-0.8.7.jar` to classpath (it is also not OSGi) and export the following package:

```
   <package name="org.odftoolkit.odfdom.doc"/>
   <package name="org.odftoolkit.odfdom.dom"/>
   <package name="org.odftoolkit.odfdom.dom.element.draw"/>
   <package name="org.odftoolkit.odfdom.dom.element.office"/>
   <package name="org.odftoolkit.odfdom.dom.element.style"/>
   <package name="org.odftoolkit.odfdom.dom.element.table"/>
   <package name="org.odftoolkit.odfdom.dom.style"/>
   <package name="org.odftoolkit.odfdom.incubator.doc.office"/>
   <package name="org.odftoolkit.odfdom.incubator.doc.style"/>
   <package name="org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg"/>
   <package name="org.odftoolkit.odfdom.dom.attribute.fo"/>
   <package name="org.odftoolkit.odfdom.dom.attribute.style"/>
   <package name="org.odftoolkit.odfdom.dom.attribute.table"/>
   <package name="org.odftoolkit.odfdom.dom.element"/>
   <package name="org.odftoolkit.odfdom.dom.element.svg"/>
   <package name="org.odftoolkit.odfdom.dom.element.text"/>
```

However it didn't help and I still get `NullPointerException`.

These are my questions:

1. What is the reason I get null converter and how to fix it?
2. What library does XDocReport use itext or odfdom for converting?

Comment: Please take your discussion over the tags on this question somewhere else. Here - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298601/must-using-stackoverflow-tags-be-approved-by-the-name-rights-holders - is a good place.

Comment: The package to export should be org.odftoolkit.odfdom.dom and not org.odftoolkit.odfdom.doc, no?

Comment: XDocReport supports itext 2.1.7 or itext . I don't know if itext-4.2.1.jar can be used. I suggest you that you try without OSGi context.

Comment: @Angelo Replacing 4.2.1 with 2.1.7 didn't help.

Comment: Have you checked that org.odftoolkit.odfdom.converter.pdf is started? Have you some stacktrace errros?

Comment: @Angelo Yes, it is started. I started all the bundles I named in my question. They all started and I don't get any package exception or warning.

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do is to take the library, that wasn't an OSGi bundle, and wrapped it. A good tutorial on how to do this in eclipse is Lars Vogel's tutorial: [How to create Eclipse plugins from jars](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJarToPlugin/article.html).

Than export the project as a jar file by following [Creating a jar File in Eclipse](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm) tutorial, and use this in your project.

Now you should have all your dependencies resolved. Extra steps are needed in case you have dynamic class loading too.